# Firebase Realtime Database, Editor crash persistent_connection.cc(363):

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

This crash seems to only happen in the Unity Editor, not on mobile devices.
Crash seems to happen sporadically when sending GetValueAsync calls. Might be wrong here but I think it only happens if I send two GetValueAsync calls after each other.

One call to get the value of a child object and one to get parent.

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("teams").Child("teamName").GetValueAsync()...
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("teams").GetValueAsync()..
```

Once I have received the crash, Unity will freeze during the next play and force quit is the only option.

Crashlog:

```
/Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-cpp-sdk/database/src/desktop/connection/persistent_connection.cc(363): listens_.find(query_spec) == listens_.end()
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage (Firebase.Platform.PlatformLogLevel,string)
Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessage (Firebase.LogLevel,string)
Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessageFromCallback (Firebase.LogLevel,string)
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks ()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks ()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update ()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update ()
```

Has anyone seen this crash before or have any idea of why it appears?

Firebase version: 9.0.0